# Anyone knows what i have to do ? Excel in C# Error

Tags: c#, excel

I am in the process of writing a program.
And in the Excel file is a table with categories and next a gap for the number. In the program, you should then be able to select the category with a comboBox and then just press a button and already, for example, the category Misc from 2 to 3.
However, this does not quite work for me as I would like with me the following error in my Excel class on line 27 :

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
"The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property, or indexer."
```

I have already tried a lot but nothing works

Main Class:
https://hastebin.com/uxijadegig.cs
Excel Class:
https://hastebin.com/xukoqupiqi.cs

Code Part:

```
ws.Cells[i, j].Value2++;
```

Comment: Pro tip: It's helpful for folks reviewing your question to see what you've already tried. I recommend updating the question with some of the things you have tried for some more context.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this : ws.Cells[i, j].Value2++;

You have to know that an array, in c#, only contains values, which cannot be incremented like and index.

To correct this, you should do :

```cs
class ExcelCell
{
    public object Value2 { get; set; }
}
internal static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExcelCell[,] cells = new ExcelCell[2, 2]
        {
            {
                new ExcelCell() { Value2 = 1 },
                new ExcelCell() { Value2 = 2 },
            },
            {
                new ExcelCell() { Value2 = 3 },
                new ExcelCell() { Value2 = 4 },
            }
        };

    Console.WriteLine("cells[0, 0].Value2: " + cells[0, 0].Value2);

    // cells[0,0]++ // won't work. Because you try to increment an object.

    // You have to unbox the object into it's actual type..
    int? x = cells[0, 0].Value2 as int?;

    if (x.HasValue) // if this works..
    {
        x++; // you can increment it..
        cells[0, 0].Value2 = x; // and put it back in place..
    }
    Console.WriteLine("cells[0, 0].Value2: " + cells[0, 0].Value2);
}
```

Comment: Your explaination is a littlebit confusing. The problem is that, `Value2` is an `object` and has to be unboxt. This would work: `int[,] tmp = new int[1, 1] { { 1 } }; tmp[0, 0]++; Console.WriteLine("cells[0, 0].Value2: " + cells[0, 0].Value2);`

Comment: Thank you @Kara this is more explainative for him.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but it still does not work ....
I just want to just select a theme in my combo box, press the button and then in the excel table at the theme I've selected by 1 rises

So like a list of lines, so to speak

Comment: @Juflos If this don't work. Please clarify your question.